# How do I connect my jquery dial to a changing variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using rmanivannan's speedometer jquery plugin (https://github.com/rmanivannan/speedometer-jquery-plugin) in my code, but don't have a lot of experience with jquery.

How can I update the speedometer to respond to a changing variable, rather than to the number keyed in to the box?  I assume it will be something in the 'eventListenerType' area, but I can't find what this would be.

My example code is shown below - my variable BoatSpeed initially starts as 0, but changes over time as the user controls the boat.  I would want the speedometer to show in real time what the BoatSpeed value is.

css

```
<link href="https://rmanivannan.github.io/demos/speedometer-reusable/css/speedometer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

html

```
<input id="BoatSpeedometer"/>
```

javascript

```
<script src="https://rmanivannan.github.io/demos/speedometer-reusable/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://rmanivannan.github.io/demos/speedometer-reusable/js/speedometer.js"></script>

var BoatSpeed = 0;

$("#BoatSpeedometer").myfunc({divFact:10,eventListenerType:'keyup'});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can trigger `keyup` event of BoatSpeedometer.

Comment: Do you want to trigger the BoatSpeedometer change event from variable instead of input box typing?

Comment: Hi Aria, thanks for your comment.  There is already a keyup event on the BoatSpeedometer, but I don't know how to link this to my variable?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jitendra Joshi, yes that's exactly what I want!

Comment: @Deborah , An easy way is initiating `BoatSpeed` to input and then call `$("#BoatSpeedometer").keyup()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've done : when the `keydown` event is triggered, the value of the input field is modified based on your `BoatSpeed` variable (in my example, you can change the speed with up and down arrow keys).
I don't think you can change the value of the speedometer manually without changing the value of the input field so I think there's no better solution.

```
<link href="https://rmanivannan.github.io/demos/speedometer-reusable/css/speedometer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<input id="BoatSpeedometer" style="display: none;"/>
<script src="https://rmanivannan.github.io/demos/speedometer-reusable/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://rmanivannan.github.io/demos/speedometer-reusable/js/speedometer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var BoatSpeed = 0;
        $("#BoatSpeedometer").myfunc();

        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 38)
                BoatSpeed += 10;
            else if (e.which == 40)
                BoatSpeed -= 10;
            $("#BoatSpeedometer").attr("value", BoatSpeed).trigger("change");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also note that the input field can be hidden.

Comment: Hi Bastien, that's really helpful thank you.  Would the syntax be the same if the variable was not changing by the keychange function, but as a result of a calculation from other inputs?  I can get your code to run perfectly but I'm struggling to update it away from your keychange example.

Comment: @Deborah Yes of course, you just need to call `$("#BoatSpeedometer").attr("value", BoatSpeed).trigger("change");` whenever you change the `BoatSpeed` variable.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed!